# Extracting configuration from React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component, I create some input fields based on some configuration array object i.e.

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const [clientId, setClientId] = React.useState('')
  const [clientName, setClientName] = React.useState('')
  .
  . 
  . 

  const configToExtract = [{
     label: ‘Client ID’,
     id: ‘clientId’,
     placeholder: ‘Enter client ID, e.g. integration-client’,
     type: ‘text’,
     stateCallback: setClientId
   },
   {
     label: ‘Client name’,
     id: ‘clientName’,
     placeholder: ‘Enter client name, e.g. Integration Client’,
     type: ‘text’,
     stateCallback: setClientName
   },...]

   // maps config entries to jsx
   const toJsx = configEntry => { ... }

   return (
     <div>
        {configToExtract.map(entry => toJsx(entry))}
     </div>
   )
}
```

I map the configuration array object to jsx

```
configToExtract.map(entry => toJsx(entry))
```

I would like to extract the configuration array to a different file so my component is not polluted with configuration boilerplate, but the issue is

```
stateCallback: setClientId
```

in the configuration array objects - I pass here references to React Hook's state methods from my component, which will be inaccessible in the new configuration file.

```
// fileWithExtractedConfig.js

const extractedConfig = [{
     label: ‘Client ID’,
     id: ‘clientId’,
     placeholder: ‘Enter client ID, e.g. integration-client’,
     type: ‘text’,
     // how to access setClientId in separate config object?
     stateCallback: setClientId
   },
   {
     label: ‘Client name’,
     id: ‘clientName’,
     placeholder: ‘Enter client name, e.g. Integration Client’,
     type: ‘text’,
     // how to access setClientName in separate config object?
     stateCallback: setClientName
   },...]

export default extractedConfig
```

THE QUESTION:
Is there a better way/pattern to extract such config from components? Any tips to solve my problem?

Code example -> https://codepen.io/pjeziorowski/project/editor/ZPWgnj

Comment: Any producible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's unclear what you trying to configure, `stateCallback: setClientId` may work for configuring component's child, you should show a better example of what you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DennisVash, I edited question, I hope it's now more clear, I also created a simple codepen example - > https://codepen.io/pjeziorowski/project/editor/ZPWgnj

Comment: you may just make `toJsx` to be a separate component taking config entry as `{...props}`

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is defining a `config.js` file and extract it.

In this case, you want to add another dynamic property to such config, one way is to map the `setters` to `JSX`:

```
// config.js
const config = {
  label: 'Client ID',
  id: 'clientId',
  placeholder: 'Enter client ID, e.g. integration-client',
  type: 'text'
};

export default config;

// SomeComponent.jsx

import configEntry from './config.js';

// Object to JSX mapper
const toJsx = configEntry => {...};

const SomeComponent = props => {
  const [clientId, setClientId] = React.useState('');
  const [clientName, setClientName] = React.useState('');

  // more setters
  const settersToMap = [setCliendId, setClientName];

  // Map setters to JSX
  return (
    <div>
      {settersToMap.map(stateCallback => toJsx({ ...config, stateCallback }))}
    </div>
  );
};
```